# Pass an include parameter in Pug template from ExpressJS?

Tags: javascript, express, templates, pug

I'm new to Pug and ExpressJS and can't figure out how to do a simple thing: passing a template path from Express to Pug.

Here's an example of what I have in mind, with the variable named `pageContent` :

**./app.js**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', {title: 'Some Title', pageContent: 'includes/somePage.html'})
})
```

**./views/index.pug**

```
html
  head 
    include includes/head.html
    title= title
  body
    include includes/header.html
    include #{pageContent}
    include includes/footer.html
```

Any idea what I am missing ? Thank in advance for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please ensure you are using:

```
app.set('view engine', 'pug')
```

Also, [dynamic import](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/2030) is not allowed yet, so your include can't be variables

Answer (score 0):

Since the pageContent is being passed in via the render function, should this be:

```
html
  head 
    include includes/head.html
    title= title
  body
    include includes/header.html
    #{pageContent}
    include includes/footer.html
```